# Can't find class in a namespace / header file

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, header-files

I made a class and split it into a source and header file, but I can't get them to talk to each other.

My header file, `GridLayout.h` that looks something like this:

```
#ifndef GRIDLAYOUT_H_INCLUDED
#define GRIDLAYOUT_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include <types.h>
#include "GridPlaceable.h"

namespace Spaceships {

class GridLayout {
    //consider replace with std::list
    typedef std::vector<GridPlaceable*> column;

    public:
        GridLayout();
        ~GridLayout();

        void arrange();
        void splitColumn(size_t colNo, distance position);
        void splitRow(size_t rowNo, distance position);
        bool placeOne(GridPlaceable* thatOne);

private:
        bool tryToFit(GridPlaceable* thatOne, size_t startCol, size_t startCell);

        std::vector<column> wholeGrid;
        std::vector<GridPlaceable*> toPlace;

        std::vector<distance> rowHeights, colWidths;
        std::vector<size_t> firstEmpties;

        bool mandates;
};

};
```

`GridLayout.cpp` looks like:

```
#include "GridLayout.h"

namespace Spaceships {

GridLayout::GridLayout() {

}

//GridLayout::aBunchOfOtherFunctions() { }

}

#endif
```

When I compile, I get a whole slew of `GridLayout does not name a type` errors. What could be causing this? I seem to remember solving a similar problem once by throwing in a bunch of semicolons, but that doesn't seem to be working this time.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to help you with a syntax error.  In which case, you will need to post *real* code, otherwise we'll end up chasing irrelevant problems.

Comment: Is the real code???? you are missing `;` after class definitions, constructor declaration, namespace declaration?

Comment: @EdChum, the namespace semicolon is optional.

Comment: @chris really, didn't know that always added it out of habit, still the code posted has a slew of other issues and if it's not the actual code this is another guessing game again on SO

Comment: Sorry, sorry. I posted my actual header file.
The cpp file does start out that way, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I'll put this here in case it helps somebody.

I must have set GridLayout.h to be compiled at some point, then changed it back, because there was a GridLayout.gch lying around in the directory. So the compiler must have gone straight for that and ignored the .h altogether. I deleted that file and now it shows me all the *real* errors in my code.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 5):

Your "actual header file" contains two declarations of the default constructor:

```
public:
    GridLayout();
    GridLayout();
```

You should remove one of these.

**Edit**: and now you are missing an `#endif` at the end of the header, and have one too many at the end of the `.cpp` file...

Comment: **Never** would have guessed that.

Comment: Oh, actually, I fixed that one in my code, but I guess I forgot to fix it here. I'll do that now.